# Каждой строке файла txt присвоить переменную php

Tags: php, txt

Хочу сгенерировать вывод строки php в которых будут записаны переменные.
Имеется файл txt со следующим текстом:

```
[10.8.1.42] comp-vm3
[10.8.1.49] comp-vm2
[10.8.1.62] ksc
```

В php считываю файл txt и разделяю на строки через `explode`:

```
<?php 
$fd = fopen("1111.txt", 'r') or die("не удалось открыть файл");
while(!feof($fd))
{
    $str = htmlentities(fgets($fd));
    $arr_ph = explode(" ",$str);
    foreach($arr_ph as $i){
    echo $i . "<br />";
    }
}
fclose($fd);
?>
```

Получаю следующий вид:

```
[10.8.1.42]
comp-vm3
[10.8.1.49]
comp-vm2
[10.8.1.62]
ksc
```

Хочу теперь каждой строке присвоить переменную `$a и $b` и записать в строку:

```
<p>бла бла бла <?php $a ?> бла бла бла  <?php $b ?></p>
```

Чтобы потом выводилось по типу:

```
 <p>бла бла бла <?php $a ?> бла бла бла  <?php $b ?></p>
 <p>бла бла бла <?php $a ?> бла бла бла  <?php $b ?></p>
 <p>бла бла бла <?php $a ?> бла бла бла  <?php $b ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

сложите все добро это в массив

```
 $content = file_get_contents("1111.txt");
 $data = array_map(function($line){ 
             [$ip, $name] = explode(' ', $line);
             return ['ip' => $ip, 'name' => $name];
           });
```

далее выводите как вам надо

```
foreach($data as $d){
    echo "bla bla {$d['ip']} bla bla {$d['name']} bla bla"

    // ?>
    // bla bla <?= $d['ip']?> ....
    // <? 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответы, но решил самостоятельно таким образом:

```
$tmp = explode("\r\n", file_get_contents('1111.txt'));
foreach($tmp as $tmp_str)
{
    if(!empty($tmp_str))
    {
      $arr = explode(' ',$tmp_str);
      echo 'бла бла бла='.$arr[0].' бла бла бла='.$arr[1].' бла бла бла <br/>';

    }
    
}
```